# Probability - A standard die is thrown 3 times. What is the probability that all 3 numbers are different?

Tags: probability

**A standard die is thrown 3 times. What is the probability that all 3 numbers are different?**

I understand how to do it with 1x(5/6)x(4/6), but wouldn't you have to repeat it for the 1 being for any roll like:

[1x(5/6)x(4/6)] + [(5/6)x1x(4/6)] + [(5/6)x(4/6)x1]

Comment: Your underlying difficulty is not formal mathematics but instead, undeveloped intuition.  The remedy is to find the right probability book for you, with many, many exercises, open it to page 1, and work through (hopefully) all of the exercises.  This will develop your intuition.

Comment: $1$ (or $\frac66$) is the probability that the number shown on the *first roll* is not the same as on any previous roll. Likewise, $\frac56$ and $\frac46$ are probabilities for the second and third rolls.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Since we want the rolls to be unique, there are six ways to get the first number, five ways to get the second and four ways to get the third. There are $6^3$ total outcomes so this is a case of simple probability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $1$ represents the probability for a specific die showing any number.

The $5/6$ represents the *conditional* probability for a second die showing another number, given whatever number that first die shows.

The $4/6$ represents the *conditional* probability for a third die showing another number, given those first and second dice show different numbers.

**It does not matter which die you pick as first, second, or third, just that they are three different die.**  The product calculates the probability for the same event: That the three die results are distinct.

---

Let $\mathcal R=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ be the possible outcomes of a single die roll and $D_1,D_2,D_3$ be the outcomes of the three die rolls.

$${\mathbb P(D_1\neq D_2, D_2\neq D_3, D_3\neq D_1)\\= \mathbb P(D_1\in\mathcal R)\;\mathbb P(D_2\neq D_1\mid D_1\in\mathcal R)\;\mathbb P(D_3\notin\{D_1,D_2\}\mid D_2\neq D_1)\\= \mathbb P(D_1\neq D_3\mid D_3\in\mathcal R)\;\mathbb P(D_2\notin\{D_1,D_3\}\mid D_1\neq D_3)\;\mathbb P(D_3\in\mathcal R)\\\vdots} $$